# Type inference with existential type

Tags: scala, generics

I have a generic trait `SomeTrait` defined as so:

```
trait SomeTrait[T] {
  def foo(t: T): String
}
```

And methods `bar` and `qux` as so:

```
def bar[T](t: SomeTrait[T]): T
def qux: List[SomeTrait[_]]
```

I do not have control over the above. I am trying to operate on the list returned by `qux`, like so

```
qux map { x => x.foo(bar(x))}
```

However, the compiler complains that the types don't match up. As far as I know this should be fine.

I have tried adding a generic method (signature `[T](SomeTrait[T])String`), and calling that to do the work, but the compiler still complains. I *can* cast my way around it like this:

```
qux map { x =>
  val casted = x.asInstanceOf[SomeTrait[T forSome { type T }]] // !!!
  casted.foo(bar(casted))
}
```

But this is even more perplexing, as `x` already has the type `SomeTrait[_]` and `SomeTrait[T forSome { type T }]` means the same thing. The only difference that I'm aware of is that the former is a shorthand for the latter that makes the compiler create its own synthetic names. I'm hoping there's a better way to do this. I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250561/scala-type-inference-on-an-existential-type) however I don't think it applies.

Comment: The latter example doesn't compile either. `bar` expected type `T`, but qux basically returns a `List[SomeTrait[Any]]`, which doesn't match it's type `T` argument.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov If you try `def qux: List[SomeTrait[Any]]`, it'll work fine, so that's not the problem.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The latter compiles just fine.

Comment: @HTNW Can you post a complete reproduce?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov [From the REPL](http://pastebin.com/tWys49R4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use a type variable to give a name to `T`:

```
qux map { case x: SomeTrait[t] => x.foo(bar(x)) }
```

This way the compiler knows `bar(x): t` and so it's an acceptable argument to `x.foo`.

Or, alternately, you can combine `foo` and `bar` into one method (remember that methods can be local, so you can just define it where you need it):

```
def fooOfBar[T](x: SomeTrait[T]) = x.foo(bar(x))
qux map { fooOfBar(_) }
```

Comment: What is `t` and how is it an acceptable argument to `x.foo`? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It's a type variable pattern, see http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#type-patterns. It just lets you give a name to the existential parameter in a pattern match, as the first sentence says. And because `SomeTrait[T].foo` need a `T` parameter, then of course `SomeTrait[Int].foo` needs `Int` and `SomeTrait[t].foo` needs `t`.

Comment: The latter is actually *really* strange, as omitting the braces (`qux map fooOfBar`) causes the compiler to complain about types again. But it works fine the way it's given. Why does that happen?

Comment: If you write `qux map fooOfBar`, this is really `qux map fooOfBar[T]` where `T` has to be inferred by the compiler. And there is no value of `T` which would work (if it did, it would have to be one `T` for all elements of `qux`). `qux map { fooOfBar(_) }` is short for `qux map { x => fooOfBar[T](x) }` and now `T` can depend on `x`.