# Mapping over a list of existential types

Tags: scala, types, polymorphism, existential-type

I have a list of existientially-typed objects I want to map over. Something like this:

```
sealed abstract class IntBox(val v: Int)
case object IB1 extends IntBox(1)
case object IB2 extends IntBox(2)

case class Adder[A  <: IntBox](ib: A, v: Int) {
  def add(i: A) = v + i.v
}

val adders: List[Adder[_ <: IntBox]] = List(Adder(IB1, 0), Adder(IB2, 0))

adders.map(adder => adder.add(adder.ib))
```

However, I'm getting an error like

```
found: adder.ib.type
required: _$1
```

I feel it's something like because the `map` somehow unifies the different `IntBox`s into one unobtainable anonymous type...

Can I get what I want without casting (i.e. `adder.asInstanceOf[Adder[adder.ib.type]]...`?

Comment: What Scala version is that? Scastie and my local scala install give "traits or objects may not have parameters" long before they get even close to the list.

Comment: haha, sorry I mean abstract class

Comment: By the way, it turns out that this is actually a duplicate (or at least very close to being a duplicate), and the solution is literally the same: [Q: Type inference with existential type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627415/type-inference-with-existential-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type is not unobtainable, you can get it using type pattern matching:

```
adders.map{ case a: Adder[t] => a.add(a.ib) }
```

Here, the existential type parameter is bound to type variable `t`, and the compiler can correctly infer additional properties of `t` that it cannot infer for the whole list.

Refer to section [8.3.1 of the Specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#type-patterns) for more details.

---

**Full code with `trait` replaced by `class` to make it compile**

```
sealed abstract class IntBox(val v: Int)
case object IB1 extends IntBox(1)
case object IB2 extends IntBox(2)

case class Adder[A  <: IntBox](ib: A, v: Int) {
  def add(i: A) = v + i.v
}

val adders: List[Adder[_ <: IntBox]] = List(Adder(IB1, 0), Adder(IB2, 0))

adders.map{ case a: Adder[t] => a.add(a.ib) }
```

Comment: This cries out for more explanation, because it works just as well with just `case a =>`.  Whatever is going on doesn't involve explicit type patterns.

Comment: @JoePallas That's an interesting observation! Honestly: I don't know why this happens. I assume that whatever is going on, it still involves pattern matching. Printing partially compiled code wasn't that enlightening so far. Do you have a clear explanation why it works for `case a => ...`, but not for `a => ...`, or was this comment meant as additional homework for me? ;) I think this would be a good question on its own. Would you want to ask and/or answer the question? Or should I ask it and try to answer it myself?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I wasn't intending to assign homework, but I have no clue about the difference.  I just stumbled onto it exercising my curiosity about why matching to an unused type variable would matter.  It's certainly far beyond my understanding.

Comment: @JoePallas I've decided to write it up as a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49712171/scala-lists-with-existential-types-why-does-map-case-t-work-but-m/49712407#49712407), and then answer it myself (apparently, this is explicitly [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). I hope it explains a few more details that that this answer was "crying for".