# Why is pattern match needed to preserve existential type information?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, existential-type

A blog describing how to use type classes to avoid F-bounded polymorphism (see [Returning the "Current" Type in Scala](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html)) mentions near its end:

> The problem here is that the connection between the types of `p._1` and `p._2` is lost in this context, so the compiler no longer knows that they line up correctly. The way to fix this, and in general the way to prevent the loss of existentials, is to use a pattern match.

I have verified the code mentioned does not work:

```
pets.map(p => esquire(p._1)(p._2))
```

while the other pattern matching variant does:

```
pets.map { case (a, pa)  => esquire(a)(pa) }
```

There is also another variant not mentioned which also works:

```
pets.map{case p => esquire(p._1)(p._2)}
```

What is the magic here? Why does using `case p =>` instead of `p =>` preserve the existential type information?

I have tested this with Scala 2.12 and 2.13.

Scastie link to play with the code: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/480It2tTS2yNxCi1JmHx8w

The question needs to be modified for Scala 3 (Dotty), as existential types no longer exists there (pun intended). It seems it works even without the `case` there, as demonstrated by another scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/qDfIgkooQe6VTYOssZLYBg (you can check you still need the `case p` even with a helper class in Scala 2.12 / 2.13 - you will get a compile error without it).

Modified code with a helper `case class`:

```
case class PetStored[A](a: A)(implicit val pet: Pet[A])

val pets = List(PetStored(bob), PetStored(thor))

println(pets.map{case p => esquire(p.a)(p.pet)})
```

Comment: This isn't a real answer, but my guess is that the difference is due to the Scala 2 compiler's special-case handling of existentials in pattern matching that's designed to support GADTs and related use cases. I don't think this is something you'll be able to track down to a statement in the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/49712407/5205022, consider the snippet

```
pets.map { p =>
  val x = p._1
  val y = p._2
  esquire(x)(y)
}
```

after typechecking `-Xprint:typer` becomes

```
Hello.this.pets.map[Any](((p: (A, example.Hello.Pet[A]) forSome { type A }) => {
  val x: Any = p._1;
  val y: example.Hello.Pet[_] = p._2;
  Hello.this.esquire[Any](x)(<y: error>)
}))
```

whilst the snippet with pattern matching

```
pets.map { case (a, pa) =>
  val x = a
  val y = pa
  esquire(x)(y)
}
```

after typechecking becomes

```
 Hello.this.pets.map[Any](((x0$1: (A, example.Hello.Pet[A]) forSome { type A }) => x0$1 match {
  case (_1: A, _2: example.Hello.Pet[A]): (A, example.Hello.Pet[A])((a @ _), (pa @ _)) => {
    val x: A = a;
    val y: example.Hello.Pet[A] = pa;
    Hello.this.esquire[A](x)(y)
  }
}));
```

We note that in the latter pattern matching case, the existential type parameter `A` is re-introduced

```
val x: A = a;
val y: example.Hello.Pet[A] = pa;
```

and so relationship between `x` and `y` is re-established, whilst in the case without pattern matching the relationship is lost

```
val x: Any = p._1;
val y: example.Hello.Pet[_] = p._2;
```

Comment: I read the linked answer a few times and I think perhaps after a few more times I will undestand it. Meanwhile I have created another Scastie with no existentials (https://scastie.scala-lang.org/0UJSY8zpT32TwpBCv8cIUg), a helper case class is used instead. I have run `-Xprint:typer` on it and this time I afraid I do not see any meaningful difference.